# Logstash with persistent queue

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, filebeat

I have started logstash using following configurations:

Inside ***logstash.yml***:

```
queue.type: persisted
queue.max_bytes: 8gb
queue.checkpoint.writes: 1
```

**configuration file:**

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5043"
    }
}
filter {
    grok {
        match => {
            "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"
        }
    }
    geoip {
        source => "clientip"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "test"
        document_type => "tw"
    }
}
```

I have such situation.

1. Imagine elasticsearch is turned off
2. **Now imagine, while elasticsearch is turned off, logstash received logging events**
3. Now imagine we turn logstash off too

Now, if I turn logstash and elasticsearch on, logstash doesn't send the messages which were received during step 2  -- **that is when elasticsearch was turned off and logstash was receiving events**.

Comment: In which order do you turn Logstash and Elasticsearch back on after step 3? First ES, wait till green, then Logstash?

Comment: are you having this issue or asking a question about what we think will happen in such case ?

Comment: Why not use buffer files which will be removed after maybe 3 days?

Answer (score 2):

Is that all you have in logstash.yml for your pipeline?  You should be defining your pipeline settings in either logstash.yml or pipelines.yml.  For example, it should look like:

```
- pipeline.id: Beats
  path.config: "/LogStash/pipelines/beatspipeline.yml"
  queue.type: persisted
  path.queue: /Logstash/data/queue
  queue.max_bytes: 10gb
```

The documentation doesn't explicitly state you must configure per pipeline settings, but I know this method has always worked.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays Logstash Persistent Queues behave like this:
"When the persistent queue feature is enabled, Logstash will store events on disk. Logstash commits to disk in a mechanism called checkpointing."

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/persistent-queues.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/persistent-queues.html#durability-persistent-queues